# "Кракозябры" вместо html-кода в php curl парсере

Tags: php, curl

Делаю парсер страницы интернет-магазина https://radugakamnya.ru/catalog/biryuza_10/ на php curl, вот пример кода:

```
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://radugakamnya.ru/catalog/biryuza_10/');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:23.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/23.0");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    $html = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    print_r($html);

Однако, получаю набор кракозябр вместо html страницы. Подскажите, в чем может быть причина?
```

Comment: Покажите, что именно вы получаете? Что за кракозябры

Comment: Вместо html-тегов вот что: ���{���u ��m�

Comment: Попробуйте добавить `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING , "gzip");`

Comment: Помогло, спасибо большое!